# Could sponges swim with their inner currents?

Tags: creature-design, sea-creatures

Sponges are sessile animals with a unique way of getting nutrients: Instead of a mouth, they have many pores through which water can flow. This water then leaves through a single canal, with suspended materials being extracted and consumed

Filter-feeding is found amongst motile animals of all scales, and comb jellies are capable of swimming, to some degree, with just cilia

On the other hand, sponges lack nerves, which seem like it would severely limit their ability to swim, and to use that ability

The specific sponge I'd like to know about would be around 20-30cm long and 5-8cm wide, with a leucon anatomy

Would this sponge realistically be able to swim by its water flow system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sure.  But not fast.**

As you note, a sponge can generate a current.  Water comes in thru pores via the work of little flagellated cells and then exits through a common exit path.

[Current-induced flow through living sponges in nature](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/74/5/2069.full.pdf)

> When ambient flow is minimal, a steady current through the osculum
> presumably reflects the pumping activity of the sponge. For the
> present animals, such active pumping rates ranged from 7.5 to 22 cm
> sec1. No particular correlation was noticed between this pumping rate
> and either species, size, or habitat. And these flow speeds are
> similar to those, between 7.9 and 17.3 cm sec1, obtained by Reiswig
> (8) on three very much larger species. I estimate that the rate of
> water volume transport per unit volume of sponge per unit time
> resulting from active pumping is within a factor of two of 0.20 sec1
> for the present animals.

It was interesting that big animals and small animals produced similar flow rates.  Not what you would expect.  But for the OP:  if you can generate flow within your body you can in theory propel yourself with that flow.  The question is how fast.  If you are neutrally buoyant you don't need to fight gravity.  As far as lateral motion more massive things will be slower.  Less hydrodynamic things will be slower.  But clearly slowth is compatible with life.  You don't need to be a swordfish.  There are lots of swimming animals that are slow.

I looked for a while because I was sure there was a micro-organism with a hollow body that used flagella along the internal path of its hollow body.  I could not turn one up!  If anyone can find that thing, link please.

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of [ctenophora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctenophora) (comb jellies)?

Comment: @StarfishPrime - I dont think the comb jellies are hollow either.  I was vaguely thinking of rotifers or Stentor (not hollow) or maybe hollow sponge or echinoderm larvae (don't exist).

Comment: [Sea Salps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salp) are not micro- but they propel themselves by pumping water through their tube bodies.

Comment: @Daron - I did not know there were tunicates that were free swimming as adults!  How super cool!  It feels to me like finding a $50 bill on the ground.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

As they are now, probably not. I've found this paper [The Role of Current Induced Flow in the Design of the Sponge Body Plan](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3236749/) which suggests that actively pumping water through their bodies already uses up a significant portion of the energy they can generate.

That's not to say that there isn't some room for handwaving in sponge-*like* things.

From the wikipedia article on [sponges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge#Movement):

> A few species can contract their whole bodies, and many can close their oscula and ostia.

That sounds like the beginnings of a jet-based propulsion system that might end up resembling something like a [salp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salp) (though note salps are chordates and so have a nervous system).

Cnidarians (the phylum which contains jellyfish) have nerves but  [no centralized nervous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cnidaria#Nervous_system_and_senses) but some of them can swim well enough. Development of whatever mechanism contractile sponges already use could lead to something that can squirt its way about.

> Would this sponge realistically be able to swim by its water flow system?

With a contraction-driven jet, I'd say there's a solid maybe! With regular sponge-style continuous flow I'm not so sure. It would be energetically unfavorable, I suspect.